# Implement a shared service between a library and an Angular consumer

Tags: angular, angular-library

I have a shared service between the different modules in my Angular application and I have implemented an Angular library. I want to use the shared service in the library too, i.e. if a data is updated in the consumer I want the library to be updated too.

I tried to use consumer in the `app.module`:

```
providers:[{provide: 'ParameterStorageService', useClass:ParameterStorageService},
```

in the library:

```
forRoot(ParameterStorageService) : ModuleWithProviders<any>{
    return {
      ngModule:CompanyAndDealModule,
      providers:[
        {provide: 'ParameterStorageService',useClass:ParameterStorageService}]
```

The problem that the data is not updated in the library when it is modified in the consumer.

Comment: `useClass` will create a new instance each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by @jonrsharpe: "useClass will create a new instance each time", so I changed useClass to useExisting and it works.

```
providers:[{provide: 'ParameterStorageService', useExisting:ParameterStorageService}
```